Why are languages fed as input into machines/automata as a stream and why do automata read one symbol at a time?
Consider an FSM augmented with a camera. The input is a book. First, the book is already stored without the FSM needing to have states to memorize the input. (The memory used to record the input is no longer considered as part of the machine's)
Second, because of this the FSM can read the input multiple times and in any order.
Redefining automata and languages where the input is no longer a stream but rather static and letting the FSM read multiple characters at a time changes the computational power of automata, and this is more realistic because machines in real life can do this.
For example, this is a non-regular language: {0^n 1^n| n ≥ 0}. But if a string from this language is written down, an FSM can read the input taking two characters at a time starting from both the beginning and end. As soon as the FSM sees any pairs like 00 or 11, it will reject.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-way_finite_automaton

Two-way automata, as suggested by D.W., may indeed read criss-cross along the tape. However they cannot mark where they have been and their acceptance power is again the regular languages. Reading from both sides in parallel (as suggested in the question)  can be done by multihead automata. As illustrated in the question, those are more powerful. I do not find a wikipedia lemma to match.
